# Grok pattern for custom response time in ns, us, ms or s - logstash

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I need to parse a response time from the custom log format so it can go via Logstash pipeline to elastic.

Example log entry be:

```
2018-11-19 23:40:00-0500 avg:30.5ms max:135ms min:6.61ms reqs:20 rsps:20 errs:0 maxcon:3 99th:135ms 95th:134ms 90th:111ms 75th:22.6ms 50th:15.6ms heap:36.7% load:1.43/0.75/0.60 cpu:26.3%
```

Avg, max, min can be in ns, us, ms or s format.
I have started from:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} avg:%{NUMBER:avg}ms
```

of course it won't work for ns etc. so I will need something like:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} avg:%{NUMBER:avg}(ns|us|ms|s)
```

However I will lose infomration as I have to scale of of values to say ms. So ns multiply by 1e6, ms -> 1e3, ms -> 1, s -> 1e-3.

What is the best approach to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found a solution finally.
First a bit of a change for the grok pattern as follows:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} avg:%{NUMBER:avg:float}(?<avgUnit>[unm]?s)
```

That gives us two elements in the event '*avg*' and '*avgUnit*' such values can be passed to the ruby script which is executed by plugin:
The script read as flows:

```
# filter runs for every event
# # return the list of events to be passed forward
# # returning empty list is equivalent to event.cancel
def filter(event)
  #convert operates on event
  convert(event ,"maxUnit", "max")
  convert(event, "minUnit", "min")
  convert(event, "avgUnit", "avg")
  convert(event, "99thUnit", "99th")
  return [event]
end

def convert(event, unitField, valueField)
  if event.get(valueField).nil?
    event.tag("__#{valueField}__not_found")
    return [event]
  end

  if event.get(unitField).nil?
    event.tag("__#{unitField}_not_found")
    return [event]
  end

  unit = event.get(unitField)
  value = event.get(valueField)
  fieldName = "#{valueField}InMs"
  case unit
  when "ns"
    event.set(fieldName, value / 1.0e6)
  when "us"
    event.set(fieldName, value / 1.0e3)
  when "ms"
    event.set(fieldName, value)
  when "s"
    event.set(fieldName, value * 1.0e3)
  else
    event.tag("__not_supported_unit_#{unit}")
  end
  return [event]
end
```

Pipeline must have configuration to include a script after match:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => ["%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp} avg:%{NUMBER:avg:float}(?<avgUnit>[unm]?s)]
  }
}
ruby {
  path => "script.rb"
}
```